# Selected "Guest questions" from other SE sites

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, site-crossover

Some questions could be asked on multiple SE sites, for example [this gamedev question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/18608/252) is likely to interest some users of [math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com). Since cross-posting is rather discouraged (for a good reason) it might be a nice feature to let some users<sup>1</sup> give these questions a "would also be nice on [other SE site]"-vote<sup>2</sup>. Then the 10 most recent questions with, say, five such votes<sup>3</sup> are displayed on that other SE site's question list - in a separate section or mixed with other questions plus the site logo, I don't know which would be better.

---

<sup>1)</sup> say, with 500 rep on both sites
<sup>2)</sup> that might also include suggesting target site tags
<sup>3)</sup> from those sites that have valid migration path connections unless a mod is involved

Comment: This would really help with overlapping questions, and keep cross-site posting down.

Comment: Ooh, what if the answers were actually synchronized across Stack Exchange sites?

Comment: @Chris even better: the idea is to link to the original question so no synchronization is required

Comment: @TobiasKienzler It would probably confuse people a bit if they clicked a question and ended up on a totally different site

Comment: @MichaelMrozek that's why I suggested either a separate section ("interesting questions from our sister sites") or or at least an icon of the target site next to the question title. Anyway, that confusion might also occur when clicking on a migrated question...

Comment: @Tobias It does, but at least those say "migrated from" in a box right under the question. I guess we could have something similar if you're coming to a question from another site

Comment: I'm not 100% convinced the solution is exactly what should happen, but the **problem** definitely exists and something like this should really  be done to address it. +1.

Comment: @Pekka thanks, and yes, it's only a first shot, I am kind of hoping someone with [more](http://ux.stackexchange.com "that is, any...") UI-skills will post a mockup of a good solution...

Comment: Related: **[Please add support for “crossover questions” between StackExchange sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199989)**